# Difference of function of "reshape" in numpy and Keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras

My situation is using FCN to do pixel-wise predictions ,I have 7 classes ,so  I feed image 512*512  and then provide the 512*512*7 for model to predict,I would like to reshape it in terms of (height*width*channels) to save the final outcome.

Since I use channels last,so the input shape makes sense to me.But the form of output shape that Keras splits out which I believe is:

```
                 (channels*height *width).
```

My try is using the function "reshape" and it works......which 
really confuses me,in my experiments,when I use reshape function the image would be totally messed up ,when in this case,it turns out working really well(using reshape function in Keras).

```
pr = m.predict( np.array([X]))[0]

#reshape to channel last and take the largest index in 7 predictions for each piexl 
pr = pr.reshape(( output_height ,  output_width , n_classes ) ).argmax(axis=-1)
```

What I expected the way that should work well is supposed to be something like np moveaxis or numpy.rollaxis.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keras is already channels last by default. Check the shapes in `model.summary()`

Comment: @DanielMöller okay I've ignored the axis= 0 ,yeah the one of layers output  shape (None, 512, 512, 7).And in my code ,the reshape function has nothing to do with the position of channel,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras is already `channels_last` by default, so you're probably doing nothing with that reshape.

Check the `model.summary()` to see the shapes.

You're correct that reshaping will mess up the images if you intend to change channel order. So you will be looking for a `Permute((3,1,2))` layer to move last to first or `Permute((2,3,1)` to move first to last.